# How to use javamelody without modifying the webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, java-melody

Suppose my web-app is running on multiple `tomcat` instances. Now I need to monitor the web-app without editing the web-app(I can't add the `jar files` to my `web-app/lib`  folder though jar can be added into `tomcat/lib`). Also existing tomcat `web.xml` is not editable. Is there any way to achieve this?